# HTML5 Video - Chrome - Error settings currentTime

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-video

When I try to set the currentTime of the HTML5 Video element in Chrome 5.0.375.86 like:

```
video.currentTime = 1.0;
```

I am getting the following javascript exception:

```
Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1
```

It works fine in Safari. Has anybody experienced this??

Comment: I haven't seen it. Can you post a link to a page that displays the error?

Comment: An old question, but I figured out an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54336444/6322589

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this (JS):

```
function loadStart(event)
{
    video.currentTime = 1.0;
}

function init()
{
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', loadStart, false);
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood an automatic solution is not possible on the iPad, since the user has to click either the poster or the movie [according to Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html).

Answer (score 0):

this is work for me

```
video = document.getElementById('video');
begin_play  = 50;
play_video_frist = true; //if you want to run only frist time    
video.addEventListener("play", capture, false);

function capture(event) 
{
     if (event.type == "play"){
         if(play_video_frist){
             play_video_frist = false;
             video.currentTime = begin_play;
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem (at least regarding Chrome) is probably on the server side.
Put `Header set Accept-Ranges bytes` in your `.htaccess` (this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9565178/1729094))

Answer (score -2):

```
$video.on 'loadedmetadata', ->
            $video[0].currentTime = parseInt(options.history)
```

with coffeescript & jQuery