# Setting HTML5 audio position

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-audio

How to jump to certain time offsets in **HTML5 Audio** elements?

They say you can simply set their [`currentTime` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html#dom-media-currenttime) (emphasis mine):

> The `currentTime` attribute must, on getting, return the current
>   playback position, expressed in seconds. **On setting**, if the media
>   element has a current media controller, then it must throw an
>   INVALID_STATE_ERR exception; otherwise, **the user agent must seek to
>   the new value** (which might raise an exception).

Alas, it doesn't seem to work (I need it in Chrome).

There are similar questions, although, no answers.

Comment: fixed it with [`audioelement.onloadedmetadata = function(){ audioelement.currentTime = time; }`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231081/selecting-the-html5-video-object-with-jquery)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Works on [my chrome](http://jsbin.com/aracov)...

```
$('#audio').bind('canplay', function() {
  this.currentTime = 29; // jumps to 29th secs
});
```

Comment: soemarko, thanks! After setting the URL of the audio to the one you provided in your jsbin, `currentTime` started to work. So I guess it was the server thing, because I used `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` to serve an audio file.

Answer (score 86):

To jump around an audio file, your server must be configured properly.

The client sends [byte range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Configuring_servers_for_Ogg_media#Handle_HTTP_1.1_byte_range_requests_correctly) to seek and play certain regions of a file, so the server must response adequately:

> In order to support seeking and playing back regions of the media that
>   aren't yet downloaded, Gecko uses HTTP 1.1 byte-range requests to
>   retrieve the media from the seek target position. In addition, if you
>   don't serve X-Content-Duration headers, Gecko uses byte-range requests
>   to seek to the end of the media (assuming you serve the Content-Length
>   header) in order to determine the duration of the media.

Then, if the server responses to byte range requests correctly, you can set the position of audio via `currentTime`:

```
audio.currentTime = 30;
```

See MDN's [Configuring servers for Ogg media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Configuring_servers_for_Ogg_media) (the same applies for other formats, actually).

Also, see [Configuring web servers for HTML5 Ogg video and audio](http://blog.pearce.org.nz/2009/08/configuring-web-servers-for-html5-ogg.html).

Comment: +1 for getting at the real problem, which is that SimpleHTTPServer is just an HTTP 1.0 server which doesn't understand byte range requests.

Comment: +1 for answering a JavaScript question with JavaScript and not a lets-all-jump-off-a-bridge-because-everyone-else-is framework.

Comment: As near as I've been able to figure out, WebKit/Chrome seeking **only** works when using `Accept-Ranges: bytes`, even for data that is already buffered (setting `Content-Length` or `X-Content-Duration` doesn't help)... This is rather strange, since not all backends are able to support content ranges (mine doesn't, since we convert files on-the-fly)... Firefox is saner, and works as expected (you can seek in buffered content, and not in unbuffered content).

Comment: Exactly what i was dealing with - Django's webserver is not able to process byte-range requests and playback always started from the beginning in Chrome regardless loaded status or passed currentTime value.

Comment: So in summary, put `Header set Accept-Ranges bytes
` in your `.htaccess` guys, thanks. I'm on this since 2013 :|

Answer (score 23):

Both **audio** and **video** media accept the `#t` URI [**Time range** property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Specifying_playback_range)

> song.mp3**#t=8.5**

To **dynamically skip** to a specific point use [HTMLMediaElement.**currentTime**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime):

```
audio.currentTime = 8.5;
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work as a direct link in all browsers, but helpful nonetheless.

Comment: I don't think the first link you posted tells you how to set the time range for an audio file.

Comment: I've found the "#t=?" format is very unreliable and usually doesn't work.

Comment: @Cerin thank you for your comment. Any insights to share? *Unreliable* in what sense? What browser? What happened?

Comment: This seems to be completely undocumented. I can't find any official references to this including in the links you posted.

Answer (score 17):

A *much* easier solution is

```
var element = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');

//first make sure the audio player is playing
element.play(); 

//second seek to the specific time you're looking for
element.currentTime = 226;
```

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you attempt to set the `currentTime` property **after** the audio element is ready to play. You can bind your function to the `oncanplay` event attribute defined in the specification.

Can you post a sample of the code that fails?

Comment: dragon, I'll try the event, thanks! Although, I set  `currentTime` from the console, when the audio is already playing.

Answer (score 9):

I was facing problem that progress bar of audio was not working but audio was working properly. This code works for me. Hope it will help you too.
Here song is the object of audio component.

HTML Part

```
<input type="range" id="seek" value="0" max=""/>
```

JQuery Part

```
    $("#seek").bind("change", function() {
            song.currentTime = $(this).val();               
        });

song.addEventListener('timeupdate',function (){

    $("#seek").attr("max", song.duration);
    $('#seek').val(song.currentTime);
    });
```

Answer (score 8):

Firefox also makes byte range requests when seeking content that it has not yet loaded- it is not just a chrome issue. 
Set the response header "Accept-Ranges: bytes" and return a 206 Partial Content status code to allow any client to make byte range requests.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Configuring_servers_for_Ogg_media#Handle_HTTP_1.1_byte_range_requests_correctly

Answer (score 5):

The @katspaugh's answer is correct, but there is a workaround that does not require any additional server configuration. The idea is to get the audio file as a blob, transform it to `dataURL` and use it as the `src` for the `audio` element.

Here is solution for angular `$http`, but if needed I can add vanilla JS version as well:

```
$http.get(audioFileURL,
        {responseType:'blob'})
        .success(function(data){
            var fr = new FileReader;
            fr.readAsDataURL(data);
            fr.onloadend = function(){
                domObjects.audio.src = fr.result;
            };
        });
```

#### cautions

1. This workaround is not suitable for large files.
2. It will not work cross-origin unless CORS are set properly.

Comment: Intereesting, alhough I'm not sure if you need a dataURL, could you possible just generate a blob URL: URL.createObjectURL(data)  ?

Comment: @bluejayke yes, after fetching the data you can do: `URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data]))`, but you need to have a new blob object from your blob data

Answer (score 1):

Set time position to 5 seconds:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myAudio");
vid.currentTime = 5;
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to fix video rewind and fast forward on chrome just add /stream? to your html request for example:

> ```
> <video src="youre.website.ext/{fileId}">
> fix.  <video src="your.website./{fileId}/stream?">
> ```

My problem was video rewind and forward didnt work on chrome but worked well on mozzila.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).