# Which jPlayer event designates the ability to start playing?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, jplayer

I have a basic jPlayer set up which plays a (150MB) audio file from AWS S3. My setup basically looks like this.

```
  jQuery(function() {
    var $player, jPlayerDefaults, progressCount;

    $player = $('<div>');
    progressCount = 0;
    jPlayerDefaults = {
      ready: function(e) {
        console.log("player ready");

        $player.jPlayer('setMedia', {
          mp3: 'http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/some/file.mp3'
        });

        return $player.jPlayer('play', 1234);
      },

      seeking: function(e) {
        return console.log("seeking");
      },

      seeked: function(e) {
        return console.log("seeked");
      },

      canplay: function(e) {
        console.log('canplay');
      },

      progress: function(e) {
        return console.log("progress", progressCount += 1);
      },

      playing: function(e) {
        return console.log("playing");
      },

      error: function(e) {
        return console.log("Error loading audio.", e);
      },

      supplied: 'mp3',
      preload: 'auto'
    };

    $player.jPlayer(jPlayerDefaults);
  });
```

My understanding from the [HTML5 audio spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#mediaevents) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9563887/574190) is that the `canplay` event designates the point at which the audio should start playing.

However, when I run the code above (with an empty browser cache), I get the following log.

```
player ready
progress 1
progress 2
progress 3
progress 4
canplay
seeking
playing
progress 5
...
progress 888
seeked
progress 889
...
progress 896
```

I only hear audio playing after the `seeked` event. This event happens a long time (minutes) after the `canplay` event.

Is this expected behavior or am I doing something wrong? Also, is jPlayer following the HTML5 `<audio>` tag spec faithfully here?

**Edit:** Incase you were wondering, AWS S3 does accept Byte-Range requests.

Comment: isn't `seeked` for when the user uses the scrubber widget? maybe it fires once at the end of the download or playtime?

Comment: I'm not sure what the "scrubber widget" is?

Comment: can you try to log also 'canplaythrough' ? it seems like it's waiting for the whole file to load

Comment: `canplaythrough` happens just after `canplay`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the problem might be: `return $player.jPlayer('play', 1234);` you are asking the player to begin play once the media is seekable to that point try just

`return $player.jPlayer('play');`
or
`return $player.jPlayer('play', 5);`

more details here http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-play the small note under the parameter, it wasn't easy to find it

Comment: But `1234` is the time that the user selected. If I can't play that point than it's no good to me.

Comment: check if aws support Accept-Ranges, in firebug see if your server's response includes the Accept-Ranges in its header.

Comment: It does. I checked that before. I'll add it to the question now that I think of it.

Answer (score 0):

An example I'm using in backbone:

```
$(this.$el.jPlayer()).bind($.jPlayer.event.canplay, _.bind(function (event) {
    that.doCanPlay();
});
```