# Apply common control in audio element in html

Tags: html

I am using the audio element of html in my website. It is working fine, but when I pause the player and go to another page, it restart from the beginning which I do not want. How can I use the common control of audio player for the website? I am new in html multimedia operations, and can not figure this out.

Html code is as follows:

```
<audio controls>
   <source src="lotus_feet.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
   <source src="lotus_feet.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use custom javascript by adding a button and onclick="document.getElementByTagName("audio")[0].pause();"

Comment: Thanks Angela, I tried this. In such case when I go to another page player restart from the beginning.

Comment: Sorry I missed that. In this case, a cookie or some kind of user info is probably required (since localstorage is no longer supported). As for setting the play cursor, see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563887/setting-html5-audio-position

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp check this out as well.