# how to detect and able to click HTML5 audio second ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

what I want to do is click the table of start tag or end tag, then the HTML5 audio will direct start from the exactly second after clicked the tag, any idea how to do it in jQuery ?

here is my code

```
<audio id="video" controls="controls" class="span4">
  <source src="file/test.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="file/test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="file/test.mp3" type="audio/wav">
  Your browser does not support the audio element. Please try other browser
</audio>
```

Here is my table to select the tag
[image]

[Here is what I found how to start the current second audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563887/setting-html5-audio-position)

```
$('#audio').bind('canplay', function() {
  this.currentTime = 29; // jumps to 29th secs
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Post html for tag table

Comment: can you tell me more detail how to post html ?

Comment: Need to see your tag table's html structure: just copy and paste it with code block as you ve done for $('#audio').bind('canplay', function() { this.currentTime = 29; // jumps to 29th s......