# How to play specific start and end duration in HTML5 audio?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I got a audio duration which is 5 minutes = 5:00, but it's too long to listen whole audio, so I got a tag which is from example 2:00 minutes to 3:00 minutes, So what I want to do is play the tag in the HTML5 audio which mean play from 2:00 minutes to 3:00 minutes.

[Here is what I found how to play the start duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563887/setting-html5-audio-position)

```
$('#audio').bind('canplay', function() {
  this.currentTime = 29; // jumps to 29th secs
});
```

**Update**

**Here is my code**

```
 <audio id="audio" controls="controls" class="span4">
  <source src="file/test.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="file/test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="file/test.mp3" type="audio/wav">
  Your browser does not support the audio element. Please try other browser
</audio>
```

**Here is my tag sample**

[image]

**AJAX**

```
$('.start_tag').click(function() {
    var sec =  $(this).attr('data-id');
    var file =  $(this).attr('data-file');
    show_tag(sec,file);
});

function show_tag(sec,file)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: config.base_url + 'index.php/qm/show_tag',
        data : {
            sec : sec,
            file : file,
        },
        success : function(data) {
            $('.show_tag').empty().append(data);
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest + " : " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
        }
    });

}
```

**Ajax Posted Data**

```
  function show_tag()
    {
        $sec = $this->input->post('sec');
        $record_filename = $this->input->post('file');
        $table = '<h4 style="margin-left:31px;">Tagged File</h4>';
        $table .= '<audio id="audio" controls="controls" class="span4 video1">';
        $table .= '<source src="'.base_url().'file/'.$record_filename.'" type="audio/ogg">';
        $table .= '<source src="'.base_url().'file/'.$record_filename.'" type="audio/wav">';
        $table .= '<source src="'.base_url().'file/'.$record_filename.'" type="audio/mpeg">';
        $table .= 'Your browser does not support the audio element. Please try other browser';
        $table .= '</audio>';
        $table .= '<script>';
        $table .= "$('#audio').bind('canplay', function() {";
        $table .= 'this.currentTime = '.$sec.';';
        $table .= '}); </script>';

/*      $table .= '<script>';
        $table .= "$('#audio').bind('timeupdate', function() {";
        $table .= ' if (this.currentTime >= '.$sec.') this.pause();';
        $table .= '}); </script>';
         */

        echo $table;
    }
```

What I did was when click the start tag, it's will go to the current audio time

Answer (score 3):

You can listen to the `timeupdate` event and pause the video once it has reached a currentTime of 3 minutes.

```
$('#audio').bind('timeupdate', function () {
    if (this.currentTime >= 180) this.pause();
}
```

Here's a list of events you can listen for on a media element:
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Media_events)

Comment: Probably better to use `>= 180` as the number is a float which means it's not sure it will be exactly 180 due to rounding errors.

Comment: Hi Sacho, After I tried your code, it's did not pause after 3:00, do you know why ?

Comment: Check out the comment Ken made and the modified code. Past that, you need to post a sample of your code.