# play specific start and end duration within audio using html-5

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I would like a create a webpage like explained in this question:
[How to play specific start and end duration in HTML5 audio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19805301/how-to-play-specific-start-and-end-duration-in-html5-audio)
My question is how to create such table and the necessary ajax to play audio with specific start and end duration. Thank you.

Comment: Please post a specific question rather than an assignment. Make an attempt and come back when you get stuck with a particular thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Media Fragments URI](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/) to play specific time ranges of media resource

```html
<label>Play first 30 seconds of audio</label><br><audio controls src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Hidden_Tribe_-_Didgeridoo_1_Live.ogg#t=0,30"></audio><br><br>
<label>Play from 30 to 50 seconds of audio</label><br><audio controls src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Hidden_Tribe_-_Didgeridoo_1_Live.ogg#t=30,50"></audio>
```