# playing audio on parallax website with skrollr JS

Tags: audio, skrollr, parallax.js

Please how I can play sound in specific positions...
Exemple : data-2000 and another data-5000

This is my code :

```
<div data-1000="" data-2000="">
    <audio id="audio01" preload="auto"/>
        <source src="audio1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        <source src="audio1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">                     
    </audio>
</div>
<div data-2000="" data-3000="">
    <audio id="audio02" preload="auto"/>
        <source src="audio2.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        <source src="audio2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">             
    </audio>
</div>
```

Example website use sound on specific data: http://www.cabletv.com/the-walking-dead
I use Skrollr JS

Thanks

Comment: You will need to provide more information is you really want someone to help. Tell us what you have tried, and where you are failing to get a result.

Comment: Hi, i have added an example for what i want, how, i can play sound between scroll data.

Comment: Does this help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563887/setting-html5-audio-position