# send audio file over http

Tags: javascript, c#, html

Soo i need to send a audio file (WAV/MP3) file over the internet to a client browser, that then is used inside a client script to be played back/processed. the server will be running a c# application. I initially approached it by using sending the file as a download to the clients hard-drive... but i had problems with accessing the file and i needed to clear the file when the client leaves the web page. I'm looking for the good advice of the community for a library or any specific methodology or course of action to tackle this problem cheers....

Comment: look into binary ajax. blob response type is ideal.

Comment: it may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563887/setting-html5-audio-position/26865633#26865633

Comment: Thank you i will look into blob responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the file from your JavaScript as a JSON or XML blob with an Ajax request.

Comment: Thanks.. I am looking into this

Answer (score 1):

Encode the audio file into a base 64 string (binary to text). Once you recieve it at the server you can decode it back to it's original format. Hope this helps!

Comment: How does this scale for larger files?