# Serving mp3 files in NodeJS for use in audio tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, html

I'm having problems serving mp3 files in NodeJS.

```
var filestream = fs.createReadStream('file.mp3');
filestream.on('open', function() {
  var stats = fs.statSync('file.mp3');
  var fileSizeInBytes = stats["size"];
  response.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
    'Content-Length': fileSizeInBytes});
  filestream.pipe(response);
});
```

I am setting the content type of the files before they are served, and the content length.

When I have the file on the page, I can play the audio and get the content's duration and it's current time.

But I cannot set it's current time like I can when I am not using NodeJS to serve the mp3 file.

```
<audio id='player' src='file.mp3'></audio>
<script>
  var duration = player.duration; // 88 seconds
  var time = player.currentTime; // 0 seconds

  player.currentTime = 10;

  var time = player.currentTime; // 0 seconds
</script>
```

Just to reitterate - when opening this page from the directory (not using nodejs as a server) I can set the currentTime of the audio element.
Why is this?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: see here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9565178/766548

Comment: Thanks levi, that certainly was the problem. I'll post an answer with the code specific to node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add an "Accept-Ranges" header to each response, and modify responses to requests with "range" headers, reading the byte range from the header and serving that content with the HTTP/1.1 206 response code.

The byte header is of the format `bytes=<start>-<end>`, e.g. `bytes=0-49`

Here is my updated code:

```
var filestream = fs.createReadStream('file.mp3');
var range = request.headers.range.replace("bytes=", "").split('-');

filestream.on('open', function() {
  var stats = fs.statSync('file.mp3');
  var fileSizeInBytes = stats["size"];

  // If the start or end of the range is empty, replace with 0 or filesize respectively
  var bytes_start = range[0] ? parseInt(range[0], 10) : 0;
  var bytes_end = range[1] ? parseInt(range[1], 10) : fileSizeInBytes;

  var chunk_size = bytes_end - bytes_start;

  if (chunk_size == fileSizeInBytes) {
    // Serve the whole file as before
    response.writeHead(200, {
      "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
      'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
      'Content-Length': fileSizeInBytes});
    filestream.pipe(response);
  } else {
    // HTTP/1.1 206 is the partial content response code
    response.writeHead(206, {
      "Content-Range": "bytes " + bytes_start + "-" + bytes_end + "/" + fileSizeInBytes,
      "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
      'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
      'Content-Length': fileSizeInBytes
    });
    filestream.pipe(response.slice(bytes_start, bytes_end);
  }
});
```

This answer was partially inspired by a gist on github found [here](https://gist.github.com/padenot/1324734).