# Randomise the play start point in html5 Audio on toggle

Tags: javascript, html, audio, toggle, playback

When the play button is clicked I want the mp3/ogg file to start playing from different randomised points.

There's only one button and no visible player for the user to toggle round. It's meant to be like a radio effect.

I am quite new to javascript so need a bit of help. I think I need to have a bit of code that tells it to skip 10-30s randomly through the file. But not sure how to go about it.

Code here:

```
<a onclick="javascript:toggleSound();"><li><i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></li></a>

<audio id="audio" preload="auto">
<source src="audio/filename.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
<source src="audio/filename.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
```

```
function toggleSound() {
  var audioElem = document.getElementById('audio');
  if (audioElem.paused)
    audioElem.play();
  else
    audioElem.pause();
```

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9563887/1267304) out

Comment: Something like `audioElem.currentTime = parseInt(Math.random() * 20) + 10;` right before `play()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function toggleSound() {
  var audioElem = document.getElementById('audio');
  if (audioElem.paused) {
    audioElem.currentTime = parseInt(Math.random() * 20) + 10;
    audioElem.play();
  }
  else
    audioElem.pause();
}
```

Comment: thanks! This seems to jump forward the first time you play-pause-play, but if you do it a second time it starts from the beginning again.Track is 1.30s do you think this is why?

Comment: I added this which seems to work audioElem.currentTime = parseInt(Math.random() * 60) + 10;

Comment: `parseInt(Math.random() * 20) + 10` should produce a number in the range of 10 to 30. You simply extended the range to 10-70. Not sure how that solves the problem you describe, but as long it works for you :)

Comment: maybe extending the range meant that it has more options of intervals to jump so more likely to be random? Probably a flawed theory but it seems to work!