# HTML5 Video.CurrentTime always set to 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I am trying to a HTML5 make a video start from a given current time. I am using a javascript function who does the follows:

```
function goToMinute(params) {
    var video = document.getElementById("video_tags");
    video.currentTime = 100;
    video.play();
}
```

This function is called on click since I have a list of positions and when I click on of them I pass the position time through parameter and then I want to start video from there.

I already checked and the params is giving me the number that I want, like 10.10 for instance (in seconds).

Since it was not working I tried to put a value there like I showed in the piece of code before:

```
    video.currentTime = 100;
```

Debugging I found out that my `video.currentTime` attribution is setting `video.currentTime = 0` and video starts from the beginning. Why is this happening?

Code that calls the function:

```
           <th><a onclick="goToMinute(<%= manual.time %>)"><%= manual.time %></a></th>
```

[image: Also I have added a picture with the debug on chrome:]

I can also add that already tried in Firefox, Chrome and Edge.

Comment: Seems to be working here http://jsfiddle.net/g0oq6h49/1/ - is it possible that you can reproduce your issue in a fiddle?

Comment: I ran into the same issue, related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15125581/3914041

Comment: I have absolutly the same trouble. Can you decide it?