# HTML5 video currentTime doesnt work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am trying to make my own HTML5 video player and i am using this code to change currentTime of a video:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

           ...

//controls.total is my seekbar

controls.total.click(function(e) {
        var x = e.pageX;
        var prog = $(this);
        var maxduration = video.duration;
        var position = x - prog.offset().left;
        var percentage = 100 * position / prog.width();
        if(percentage > 100) {
            percentage = 100;
        }
        if(percentage < 0) {
            percentage = 0;
        }
        controls.progress.css('width',percentage+'%');
        if ( video.seekable.length > 0 ) {
            video.currentTime = maxduration * percentage / 100;
        }
    });

           ...

}
```

It works just as it should to in IE9, Edge and Firefox. But It doesn't work in Chrome. It just sets currentTime to 0. Why?

Comment: hey, have you figured out why and how to solve this issue?

Comment: try online or with another server. many report that it's a Chrome bug related to the server. i solved the problem just by uploading the video on an online server and setting the full url on the `src` attribute.

Comment: I figured out an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54336444/6322589