# Video.currentTIme javascript video curent time set function not work in laravel view.blade.php

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

This is the code

```php
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
<title></title>
<!-- <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'> -->
<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' integrity='sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD' crossorigin='anonymous'>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="col-6 right-head gif-head text-center">
      <button onclick="abc()">abc</button>
      <video id="v0" controls preload>
        <source type="video/mp4" src="{{asset('assets/img/mobile.mp4')}}">
      </video>
    </div>
    
    <script>
      function abc() {
        alert('clicked');
        let video = document.getElementById('v0');
    
          video.currentTime = 26;
      }
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I stuck to this "video.currentTime = 26" function. This same code I have run in HTML and PHP extension files and it runs properly but in blade.php it's not working. In other click button it alerts clicked and then set the current time of my video to 26 seconds but in laravel blade it alerts clicked and then nothing happens

Comment: I found an answer. I hope it will help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783521/why-does-setting-currenttime-of-html5-video-element-reset-time-in-chrome